# wxPython widgets side changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, wxpython, pos

When I run my GUI on different OS that has another default display language and works from right to left (opposite to English) the widgets change their position to the opposite side (I don't use grid I choose by my self their position with pos=(POS_X,POS_Y). Someone knows how to change it that the position won't be change if I change the display language of the OS?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `wx.ALIGN_LEFT` style on the sizer or window?

Comment: Use grids. They are found in all graphic libraries for some reason. And the grid layouts have a property called "LayoutDirection"...

Comment: I didn't used grip in all of the gui and I can't add it now @Dan A.S. I tried to add wx.ALIGN_LEFT to the frame's style and it didn't work.

Comment: The grids are the way to control the layouts and display direction. I don't think you must to reinvent the wheel. But if you want... good luck xD

Comment: Someone maybe has another solution?